# Draw a mountain given altitude

Tags: code-golf, string

Take an array of nonnegative integers, such as `[1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 2, 0]`. Then, draw that as a mountain where the integers represent altitude:

```
     x  
        
    x x 
x  x    
 xx    x
```

You may use any printable non-whitespace character in place of `x`, and adding padding or whitespace after lines or the output is fine (but not required). You may optionally take one indexed inputs. Transposing the output is not allowed, but returning an array of lines is fine.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer (in bytes) per language wins.

Comment: May I print the answer with extra columns of spaces between each column?

Comment: Can we output a list of lines?

Comment: May we take the length of the array as an additional input?

Comment: Can the output be transposed? (Rows instead of columns)

Comment: @FZs No, sorry.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Sure, that's fine

Comment: @chunes Sure, I think that's allowed under standard I/O anyway.

Comment: @LuisMendo No, sorry.

Comment: Please update the post to include things you are allowing in comments (or chat) that are not currently allowed by its wording. What's allowed should not have to be found by reading comments, chat, or by word of mouth.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I wasn't aware of any things I'd allowed that weren't in the challenge body (aside from things already allowed under standard I/O). I'll try to clarify it though.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said what. 1) list of lines per comment above (maybe this is allowed by default?); 2) non-character usage in place of an `x` character ([agreed in chat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230524/draw-a-mountain-given-altitude?noredirect=1#comment528876_230541)?)

Comment: @JonathanAllan I don't think I mentioned anything either way on that in chat, but I think it'd fall under standard I/O in one way or another. It's very much an edge case though, so I think putting it in the challenge body is unnecessary. I did edit earlier to include the list of lines thing, though. Thanks!

Comment: Can we output extra lines of whitespace *before* the rest of the output?

Comment: @Alexis Sorry, no. Unless it's unpreventable output from the compiler/runtime/print function, of course.

Answer (score 17):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
×꘍R§
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C3%97%EA%98%8DR%C2%A7&inputs=%5B1%2C%200%2C%200%2C%201%2C%202%2C%204%2C%202%2C%200%5D&header=&footer=)

That's right, it's flagless.

### Explained

```
×꘍    # [(n * " ") + "*" for n in input]
  R   # [x[::-1] for x in ^]
   §  # vertically join (rotate) ^
```

Using the `L` flag would make it 3 bytes.

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 66 bytes

```python
a=input()
n=max(a)
while~n:print''.join(' x'[x==n]for x in a);n-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcbBCkBAFEbhvae4u5kphKzoPoksZkGu@GfSyNh49SF1@jr@DotDk5JlgT@DNhl4t1Fbk12LbNODzh@CoFS5OoFWFNUQmTHO7qBIArKmR8F1SkOdU/X3TZNT@1uNLw)

Comment: I'm new to golfing, could you please explain what the ~ in the `while~n:` stands for ?

Comment: @Ubikuity It is the bitwise NOT operator. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#index-96

Comment: See [golfing tips for Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54/32381). `~` is the logical operator *not*. So `while~n:<<…>>;n-=1` is a sort of for loop for n decreasing until it’s 0 (`not n` is `True` if n not equal to 0; for n=0, it’s False).

Comment: @agtoever `n` actually decreases until it reaches `-1`. https://ideone.com/GEM9L1

Comment: @Unmitigated you’re completely right.

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 5 bytes

```
$úζR»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f5fCuc9uCDu3@/z/aUEfBAIyADCMdBRMwaRALAA)

```python
$        # push "1" and the input
 ú       # for each integer in the input,
         # pad "1" with this many spaces in the front
  ζ      # tranpose, padding with spaces
   R     # reverse, the mountains should not be upside down
    »    # join by newlines
```

Comment: `»` can be removed.

Answer (score 7):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <sup><s>66</s></sup> 63 bytes

```
s=${(l/${${(On)@}[1]}*#/)}
for x;s[++i+$#s-#*x]=.
fold -$#<<<$s
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhY37YttVao1cvRVqoGUf56mQ220YWytlrK-Zi1XWn6RQoV1cbS2dqa2inKxrrJWRaytHlA4J0VBV0XZxsZGpRhiDNS0HdFGOgqGYARkGOsomIJJw1ioPAA)

-3 thanks to JoKing, but still probably too long.

Explanation:

- `${${(On)@}[1]}`: get the maximum input
- `s=${(l/*#/)}`: construct a string of spaces which is (number of inputs) × (maximum of inputs) in length
- `for x;s[++i+$#s-#*x]=.`: set the correct index of the string to a `.` for each element
- `fold -$#<<<$s`: line-wrap the string at (number of inputs) in length

Comment: Only familiar with bash, but would something like `sort -n|tail -1` save bytes for getting the max?

Comment: @Jonah That method doesn't turn out to be shorter, but Zsh has its own builtin way to sort things which I should have considered, so thanks for the hint anyway!

Answer (score 6):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 18 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
{⊖⍉⍕⍪'x',¨⍨⍵⍴¨' '}
```

```
{          ⍝ Open function
⊖⍉         ⍝ Flip diagonally and then vertically
⍕          ⍝ Make table into multiline string
⍪           ⍝ Display one element per row
'x',¨⍨      ⍝ Append an 'x' to each element
⍵⍴¨' '      ⍝ Duplicate each space 'input' times
}           ⍝ Close function
```

[Try it on online!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=q37UNe1Rb@ej3qmPelepV6jrHFrxqBeItj7q3XJohbqCei0A&f=e9Q39VHbhDQFQwUDIDRUMFIwAWIDAA&i=AwA&r=tio&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=%E2%8E%95)

Comment: ⊖⍉↑'x'↑¨⍨-1+⎕
13

Comment: @rak1507 Thanks for the idea! Not sure I understand, though. [It doesn't seem to work.](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v//Ud/UR20THnVNe9Tb@ahtonqFOpA8tOJR7wpdQ22gpIKh8f//hgoGQGioYKRgAsQGAA) Will play around with it more later!

Comment: the 13 is the byte count

Comment: rak's comment is a full program, [here](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97f@jrmmPejsftU1Ur1AHko96VxxacWi9oe6jvqkgBf/TuAwVDIDQUMFIwQSIDQA) is a TIO link for it. I'm not sure how to use it on APLgolf

Comment: Taking 1-indexed is allowed, which would shorten `-1+⎕` to `-⎕`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @rak1507 & ovs, I understand it now. You've made a lot of improvements! Are you sure you want to give it to me, or would you rather post as your own submission?

Comment: I'm fine with you updating your solution, don't know about ovs but I assume they wouldn't mind either

Comment: Sounds good, thanks a bunch @rak1507. I'm sure ovs is, yours was just a significant change so I wanted you to get the rep & credit if you wanted!

Answer (score 6):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 91 bytes

```
func[a][i: last sort copy a until[forall a[prin either a/1 = i[1][sp]]print""0 > i: i - 1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYyxCsMwDAX3fsUje6hdMgXaj@gqNIjEoQLHNrYy9Otdl@Omg6th7@@wE99OW/txpY2ESVdEaYaWq2HL5QvBlUwjHblKjBAqVROC2idUyN3jCSXP1ArzP9k0ObwwRooZnrmfBvJwA48HlqHj/gM)

-6 bytes from Galen Ivanov.

Comment: [91 bytes](https://tio.run/##FYyxCsMwDAX3fsUje6hdMgXaj@gqNIjEoQLHNrYy9Otdl@Omg6th7@@wE99OW/txpY2ESVdEaYaWq2HL5QvBlUwjHblKjBAqVROC2idUyN3jCSXP1ArzP9k0ObwwRooZnrmfBvJwA48HlqHj/gM) with some minor modifications.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
Ṭ€z0Ṛo⁶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzjWPmtZUGTzcOSv/UeO2/48aZhxuj/x/dNLDnTP@RxvqKBiAEZBhpKNgAiYNYgE)

Outputs a list of lines. +1 byte (append `Y`) if unacceptable.

Takes input 1 indexed, uses `1` as the mountain character

### How it works

```
Ṭ€z0Ṛo⁶ - Main link. Takes a list L on the left
 €      - Over each element in L:
Ṭ       -   Untruthy; Map each n to [0, 0, ..., 1] with n-1 zeros
  z0    - Transpose, padding with zeros
    Ṛ   - Reverse
     o⁶ - Replace 0s with spaces
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, even if a list of lines is acceptable you would still need to be allowed to use an integer in place of a character to remove the `Y` ("You may use any printable non-whitespace *character* in place of x").

Comment: @JonathanAllan It appears as though `Y` doesn't actually coerce integers into strings: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/y6KSHO2f8//8/2lDHSMc4FgA "Jelly – Try It Online"). However, OP confirmed in chat that both a list of lines and mixing characters/digits was fine

Comment: No it does not, but with it the code would work as a full program due to Jelly's implicit, smashing print.

Comment: The post has not been updated yet to say non-charactrers are acceptable. It's best to stick to the current wording and give the potential save than the other way around.

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 17 bytes

```
[:|.@|:' x'#~,.&1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o61q9BxqrNQVKtSV63T01Az/a3L5OekpOObk5heXKJTnF2UX6ygklZYo5OWD9FeoV9fZxljV6XFxpSZn5CukKRgCjQQjIMNIR8EETBr8BwA)

<sup>+6 thanks to Lynn for spotting a bug in the original solution: `' x'{~=\:~.`  This approach can be made to work but it's no longer golfy: `' x'{~]=/~[:i.1-@+>./`</sup>

### how

- `,.&1` Zip input with 1:

  ```
  1 1
  0 1
  0 1
  1 1
  2 1
  4 1
  2 1
  0 1
  ```
- `' x'#~` Duplicate `' x'` according to these pairs

  ```
   x   
  x    
  x    
   x   
    x  
      x
    x  
  x
  ```
- `[:|.@|:` Rotate left:

  ```
       x  

      x x 
  x  x    
   xx    x
  ```

Comment: Good spot, thanks.  Fixed solution not as nice though :(

Comment: @Lynn Original approach can be salvaged `' x'{~]=/~[:i.1-@+>./` but it's no longer shorter.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
=ⱮṀṚo⁶
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of positive integers (the 1-indexed option) and yields a list of lists of characters and integers (`1` being the choice for `x`).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/20cZ1D3c2PNw5K/9R47b/h9sj//@PNtJRMAQjIMNYR8EUTBrGAgA)** (The footer joins with newlines and then Jelly's implicit, smashing print produces the output.)

#### How?

```
=ⱮṀṚo⁶ - Link: list of integer heights, H
  Ṁ    - maximum (H) -> M
 Ɱ     - map across (h in [1..M]) with:
=      -   (H) equals (h) (vectorises)
   Ṛ   - reverse -> X
     ⁶ - space character
    o  - (X) logical OR (' ') (vectorises)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 6 bytes

```
↑ＥＡ◧xι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMqtEBHwTexQMMzr6C0RENTRyEgMcUnNa1EQ6lCSUchU1NT0/r//@hoIx0FQzACMox1FEzBpGFs7H/dshwA) Link is to verbose version of code. 1-indexed. Explanation:

```
  Ａ     Input array
 Ｅ      Map over elements
    x   Literal string `x`
   ◧    Left-padded to width
     ι  Current element
↑       Print rotated
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

1-indexed, using `"` for the peaks.

```
£QùXÃÕÔ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=o1H5WMPV1A&input=WzIsIDEsIDEsIDIsIDMsIDUsIDMsIDFd)

```
£QùXÃÕÔ     :Implicit input of array
£           :Map each X
 Q          :  Quotation mark
  ùX        :  Left pad with spaces to length X
    Ã       :End map
     Õ      :Transpose
      Ô     :Reverse
            :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 51 bytes

```ruby
->a{(-a.max..0).map{|y|a.map{|x|x==-y ??x:' '}*''}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6xWkM3US83sUJPz0ATSBdU11TWJEIYFTUVtra6lQr29hVW6grqtVrq6rW1/wtKS4oV0qKjDXUUDMAIyDDSUTABkwaxsf8B)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 67 bytes

```python
lambda x:[[v==i and'*'or' 'for v in x]for i in range(max(x),-1,-1)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKjq6zNY2UyExL0VdSz2/SF1BPS2/SKFMITNPoSIWxMwEMYsS89JTNXITKzQqNHV0DYFIM/Y/XDZNI9pQR8EAjIAMIx0FEzBpEKtpxaUABAVFmXklGpma/wE)

`for i in range(max(x),-1,-1)` -> identify how high the mountain will be, max value is first line (top), so start from max, iterate to 0

`[v==i and'*' or' ' for v in x]` -> for every integer in input set it as * if height  matches current line, set it whitespace otherwise.

[EDIT] as per @hyper-neutrino suggestion to get 3 bytes less, and wrapped in lambda as per @Razetime comment

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! You can remove three spaces here: after `'*'`, after `' '`, and after the first `]`. You may also be interested in our [Tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python).

Comment: hardcoding is not allowed as per standard i/o, so you need to wrap your code in a function.

Comment: @Razetime could be like it's now, wrapped in lambda, so input is lambda arg?

Comment: Yep, correct. You may want to read [this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7615/80214) if you have any doubts.

Comment: `lambda a:[[' x'[i==j]for j in a]for i in range(max(a),-1,-1)]`

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

-2 bytes through auto-vectorizing

```
ð*×+ðÞṪṘ⁋
```

```
ð*            # vectorised n spaces
  ×+          # append "*"
     ðÞṪ      # transpose with space as filler
        Ṙ⁋    # reverse and join by newline
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C6%9B%C3%B0*%C3%97%2B%3B%C3%B0%C3%9E%E1%B9%AA%E1%B9%98%E2%81%8B&inputs=%5B1%2C%200%2C%200%2C%201%2C%202%2C%204%2C%202%2C%200%5D&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <sub><sup><del>77</del></sup></sub> <sub><sup><del>74</del></sup></sub> <sub><sup><del>73</del></sup></sub> 70 bytes

-1 thanks to @RecursiveCo.
-3 thanks to @m90's idea

```javascript
a=>{for(i=Math.max(...a);i;i--)console.log(a.map(e=>i^e&&' ').join``)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtRCsIwEESvsl9tgs3Sin8luYEnEKVLTXRLzZY2iCCePdYKw/Bg3gz0pKWfeUomytXnXuKSIICFTNa9g8yK7ZHSHR/0UohIuuWWjdE/U0aPo9wUreukvHV88UVRQqlxEI5dpz85qFNTQb1lhX0Fh63r8/8E1oHfNVrnLw)

Takes one-indexed input.

Comment: -1 bytes for your first program: [see this link](https://tio.run/##JYtBCsIwEEX3niK7ZLAZWnFlSDyBJxCloSY6pc2UtkhBPHssFT6PB4/f@refmpGGWSd@hBxtTtZ9Io@K7MXPL@z9ohAxgSFDWkPDaeIuYMdPldY6qGBduNNZCnmSiwRsmVJdwzebXVTXqhDltlUOhThuLG//p7BOhH0FkH8)

Comment: @RecursiveCo. Good idea, applies to both of my programs. Edited in. (+ thanks for tidying up my header & footer)

Comment: A further improvement is to replace `'x'` with `1` (which gets automatically stringified by `join`), since any printable non-whitespace character is accepted.

Comment: @m90 Good point! Thinking further, I can even get rid of the literal `1` by using the `0` returned by the XOR. Thanks for the idea, merged.

Comment: Switch to the V8 engine on TIO and you can use `print`.

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think that would be an "improvement" to this solution. It would require to change the interpreter, and IMHO it would count as a "different language" for the purposes of golfing and count as a seperate solution: this would be the best of Node.js-y JS, that would be the best of V8-y JS. I chose `console.log`, because it works not just in Node.js, but pretty much all JS engines, and this supposed to be a general JS solution. Correct me if you think I'm wrong, after all, you're much more familiar with this site than I am...

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 65 bytes

```r
function(a)for(i in max(a):0)cat(c(' ','x')[1+(a==i)],'
',sep='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY2xCsMwDER3f4U2SVSDUzIV9CWlgzANaIgcUgfy964JBI7j3fJu72s9opmH9uWI0rwGGS91JwcPWO0c85W5WKNCCCh4Ir@nB5mq80cwofy@myJyNy00CeQrA54C89WZ0/0zdKn/AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 44 bytes

```
Print@@@Table[" "Unitize[#+i],{i,-Max@#,0}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P6AoM6/EwcEhJDEpJzVaSUEpNC@zJLMqNVpZOzNWpzpTR9c3scJBWcegNlbtf5pDtaGOARAa6hjpmACxQe1/AA)

Prints the mountain, using `0` instead of `x`.

Remove the `Print@@@` for -8 bytes if an array of characters and numbers is acceptable output.

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) / MATLAB, 43 bytes

```matlab
@(x)flip([accumarray([x find(x)],3)+32 ''])
```

Anonymous function that inputs a 1-based column vector and outputs a char matrix with `#` and

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0IzLSezQCM6MTm5NDexqCixUiO6QiEtMy8FKBWrY6ypbWykoK4eq/k/TSPayFrBEIyADGNrBVMwaQiUAwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-l`, 10 bytes

```
R:sXg.0ZDs
```

Takes the integers as command-line arguments. Outputs using `0` in place of `x`. [Try it here!](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/pip) Or, here's an 11-byte equivalent in Pip Classic: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/KMyqOCJdzyDKpfj/f0MuAyA05DLiMgFig/@6RTkA)

#### Explanation

```
            g is list of cmdline args; s is space (implicit)
  sXg       Convert each arg to a string of that many spaces
     .0     Append 0 to each string of spaces
       ZDs  Transpose, extending shorter strings with a default value of space
R:          Reverse the resulting list
            Autoprint, one row per line (-l flag)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
｛ ×x＋］↶
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjVCJTIwJUQ3eCV1RkYwQiV1RkYzRCV1MjFCNg__,i=JTVCMSUyQyUyMDAlMkMlMjAwJTJDJTIwMSUyQyUyMDIlMkMlMjA0JTJDJTIwMiUyQyUyMDAlNUQ_,v=8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
_.tm+*;
```

[Try it here!](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=_.tm%2B%2a%3B&input=%5B1%2C+0%2C+0%2C+1%2C+2%2C+4%2C+2%2C+0%5D&debug=0)